# No bar is highlighted in tradingview

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I would like to highlight the candlestick based on the time in trading view and wrote the below pine script without any compilation error. I followed the tutorial but no bar was highlighted with the below script. Grateful if anyone could help on it. Thanks

```
//@version=4
study("Timeline", overlay=true)

//Inputs
showHSI = input(title="Display HSI session?", type=input.bool, defval=false)
//showFX    = input(title="Display FX session?", type=input.bool, defval=false)

//Color
COLOR_TRANS = 100
GRAY_COLOR = color.rgb(120, 123, 134,COLOR_TRANS)

//Timezone
timezone = "GMT+8"

//Function returns true when the bar's time is matched
//timeinrange(res, sess) => time(res, sess) != 0

//Highlight the bar
//HSI
hsiSessionColor = iff ( (timeframe.multiplier==1 and showHSI),
     (time==timestamp(timezone, year, month, dayofmonth, 09, 15) or
      time==timestamp(timezone, year, month, dayofmonth, 09, 30) or
      time==timestamp(timezone, year, month, dayofmonth, 11, 00) or
      time==timestamp(timezone, year, month, dayofmonth, 13, 00) or
      time==timestamp(timezone, year, month, dayofmonth, 14, 30) or
      time==timestamp(timezone, year, month, dayofmonth, 16, 00) )?GRAY_COLOR:na,
     na)

//FX-Day
fxDaySessionColor = iff ( (timeframe.multiplier==5 and not showHSI),
     (time==timestamp(timezone, year, month, dayofmonth, 15, 00) or   
      time==timestamp(timezone, year, month, dayofmonth, 20, 00) )?GRAY_COLOR:na,
     na)

//FX-Week
fxWeekSessionColor = iff ( (timeframe.multiplier==15 and not showHSI),
     ((time==timestamp(timezone, year, month, dayofmonth, 15, 00) and dayofweek==3)or     
      (time==timestamp(timezone, year, month, dayofmonth, 20, 00) and dayofweek==3))?GRAY_COLOR:na,
     na)

//Highlight the bar
bgcolor(hsiSessionColor)
bgcolor(fxDaySessionColor)
bgcolor(fxWeekSessionColor)
```

Answer (score 0):

bgcolor is for coloring the background of the candle
If you want to color the candle, use the barcolor function instead :)